# Updating dataframe with rows of variable size in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have imported an excel sheet into a dataframe in Pandas. The blank values were replaced by 'NA's. What I want to do is, for each of the row values, replace them based on indices of a dictionary or dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c1':['a','a','b','b'], 'c2':['1','2','1','3'], 'c3':['2','NA','3','NA']},index=['first','second','third','last'])

>>> df1
       c1 c2  c3
first  a  1    2
second a  2    NA
third  b  1    3
last   b  3    NA
```

and I want to replace the values in each row according to the indices of another dataframe (or dict).

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(
    {'val':['v1','v2','v3']},index=['1','2','3'])

>>> df2
   val
1  v1  
2  v2 
3  v3
```

Such that the output becomes

```
>>> out
       c1 c2  c3
first  a  v1  v2
second a  v2  NA
third  b  v1  v3
last   b  v3  NA
```

How would you do this through Pandas and/or Python? One way to do it would be to search row by row, but maybe there is an easier way?

**Edit: Importantly, performance becomes an issue in my real case since I am dealing with a 'df1' whose size is 4653 rows × 1984 columns**.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think to access each cell and do a check you have to `iterrows` which is not that hard lol.

Comment: @Bobby thank you for your comment. Please feel free to post it as a new answer

Comment: Man look at these fancy answers. I'm just not confident. Learned too lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer

```
s = df1.squeeze()
df2.replace(s)
```

`replace` is very, very slow. For a larger data set like you have check the following example which is done over 30 million values (more than your 10 million values) in about 20 seconds. The lookup Series contains 900k values from 0 to 1 million.

'map' is much, much faster. The only issue with `map` is that it replaces a value not found with missing so you will have to use `fillna` with the original DataFrame to replace those missing values.

```
n = 10000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijkl'), n),
                 'c2':np.random.randint(0, 1000000, n),
                 'c3':np.random.randint(0, 1000000, n)})

s = pd.Series(index=np.random.choice(np.arange(1000000), 900000, replace=False), 
              data=np.random.choice(list('adsfjhqwoeriouzxvmn'), 900000, replace=True))

df.stack().map(s).unstack().fillna(df)
```

You can also do this which is running faster on my data but your data is very wide so it might be slower

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.map(s)).fillna(df)
```

And on a DataFrame similar to yours, I am getting 6s to complete.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000000, (5000, 2000)))
df.stack().map(s).unstack().fillna(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion works perfectly for a small test case. For instance, using a 5x4 'df1' with my real data works perfectly, but for the whole dataframe it takes too long and freezes my pc (maybe because it is processing all rows/columns, including where there are 'NA'?). Any way to improve this?

Comment: Check if `np.where` will work for you. Are all your values strings?

Comment: All the search values are integers (similarly to the working examples above). I will check it, but I need to come up with an overall rule since those integers (that serve as keys/indices) go from 1 to 100000 but not all integers are there.

Comment: (Also, please keep your previous answer since it was very helpful!)

Comment: Can you check the updated answer. `map` is much faster than `replace`

Answer (score 4):

One way would be `stack` + `replace` + `unstack` combo:

```
df1.stack().replace(df2.val).unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you don't have to stack. df1.replace(df2.val)  works.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I always thought you can't use `replace` directly on a `DF` object just like `map`. I'll let my answer remain unchanged as it would then duplicate yours.